# Django + Dropzone - I can't display files

Tags: ajax, django

I'm creating Django application with gallery. That gallery have albums and photos.
 Photos have foreign key to album.
In template I'm sending files and album id (only one person can add something to gallery, so I don't have to worry about that as a security hole). I'm sending these files with dropzone's javascript.
Then in view I use such code to save photos:

```
if 'addphotos' in request.POST:
    if ('Album' in request.POST):
        ualbum = Album.objects.get(id=request.POST['Album'])
        print(ualbum.title)#just checking, this part works
        files = [request.FILES.get('dzfile[%d]' % i) for i in range(0, len(request.FILES))]
        for ufile in files:
            p = Photo.objects.create(album=ualbum, file=ufile)
```

And something is not working there with files. Photo object is created but file is not attached to it.
In ./manage.py shell I did something like this:

```
>>> from main.models import Photo
>>> from main.models import Album
>>> album = Album.objects.get(id=8)
>>> print (album.title)
teraz zadziała
>>> photos = Photo.objects.filter(album=album)
>>> print(photos)
<QuerySet [<Photo: Photo object>, <Photo: Photo object>, <Photo: Photo object>]>
>>> for photo in photos:
...     print(photo.album.title)
... 
teraz zadziała
teraz zadziała
teraz zadziała
>>> for photo in photos:
...     print(photo.file.url)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/zeko/Pulpit/grh/stronka/s/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 70, in url
    self._require_file()
  File "/home/zeko/Pulpit/grh/stronka/s/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 47, in _require_file
    raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)
ValueError: The 'file' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Why does it happen?

Photo in my models.py:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album')
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/')
```

Media in my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Where had I did something wrong?

Comment: Do files actually get uploaded to the `'img/'` folder?

Comment: No. This folder is still empty.
And I can't get why.

Comment: Your code looks fine... Ok, shot in the dark, what about `p = Photo(album=ualbum, file=ufile); p.save()` instead of using the manager's method?

Comment: Oh God. Somebody told me on polish django irc channel to use python debugger, and  with it I found out that my files where null in view. I just copy pasted ('dzfile[%d]' % i) from an tutorial, while in my cause it had to be ('file[%d]' % i).

Comment: why are you not using  a form?